# Python pydantic validate dates

Tags: python, pydantic

My question is pretty simple and I'm surprised no one has asked it so far:

How can I validate dates in pydantic?

For example, I only want to accept dates in the range 1980.1.1-2000.1.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) for `datetime` field is what you want. You can use it as following:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from datetime import datetime

class DModel(BaseModel):
    dt: datetime

    @validator("dt")
    def ensure_date_range(cls, v):
        if not datetime(year=1980, month=1, day=1) <= v < datetime(year=2000, month=1, day=1):
            raise ValueError("Must be in range")
        return v

DModel.parse_obj({"dt": "1995-01-01T00:00"})
DModel.parse_obj({"dt": "2001-01-01T00:00"})  # validation error
```

Comment: Can I use the same validator for multiple pydantic classes/schemas/models?

Comment: Yes, as described [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#reuse-validators)

Comment: link seems broken @alex_noname

Answer (score 7):

#### Original Pydantic Answer

One common use case, possibly hinted at by the OP's use of "dates" in the plural, is the validation of multiple dates in the *same model*. This is very lightly documented, and there are other problems that need to be dealt with you want to parse strings in other date formats.

This is not explicitly in the [docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators). Well, it's there, but the circumstances where it's required are not mentioned. If you need your validator to convert a non-ISO `str` format to `date` Pydantic will discover an invalid date format *before* your validator has run.

In these circumstances it's not sufficient to just apply multiple validators, or apply one validator to multiple fields, the `pre=True` argument **also** needs to be supplied, to pre-empt the default formatting from raising an exception, before your validator can convert it:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


def validate_date(value: str) -> date:
    return datetime.strptime(value, "%d/%m/%Y").date()


class CommonModel(BaseModel):
    created: date
    modified: date
    confirmed: date
    closed: date

    _validate_dates = validator(
        'created', 'modified', 'confirmed', 'closed', pre=True, allow_reuse=True,
    )(validate_date)

data = {
    'created': '25/12/2000',
    'modified': '31/12/2000',
    'confirmed': '01/01/2001',
    'closed': '11/09/2001',
}

try:
    model = CommonModel(**data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.json())
```

The [docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) on this are so light I had to discover this myself, and I haven't found anyone else pointing this out, so I thought a demonstration of this kind of code would be helpful here.

---

#### Updated Pydantic 2.3 Answer

Pydantic 2 is better and is now, so in response to @Gibbs' I am updating with a Pydantic 2.3 solution that contains other non-date fields as well.

While Pydantic 2 documentation continues to be a little skimpy the migration to Pydantic 2 is managed, with specific migration documentation identifying some of the changes required and with the new Python 11 helpful error messages it wasn't too hard to discover.

Pydantic 2 also changes the approach a bit, with specific support for multiple fields, making cleaner code so I've used that support in this answer. If you want to use this validator with multiple models with *different* field names for the dates in those models, then you may have to revert the structure similar to my original answer.

```py
import datetime
import pydantic

class CommonModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    created: datetime.date
    modified: datetime.date
    confirmed: datetime.date
    closed: datetime.date
    number: int

    @pydantic.field_validator(
        "created", "modified", "confirmed", "closed", mode="before"
    )
    @classmethod
    def non_iso_date(
        cls, value: str, info: pydantic.FieldValidationInfo
    ) -> datetime.date:
        assert isinstance(value, str), info.field_name + " must be date as str 'dd/mm/yyyy'"
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%d/%m/%Y").date()


data = {
    "created": "25/12/2000",
    "modified": "31/12/2000",
    "confirmed": "01/01/2001",
    "closed": "11/09/2001",
    "number": 3,
    "name": "rumplestiltskin",
}

try:
    model = CommonModel(**data)
    print(model)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.json())
```

This will generate output as follows:

```
name='rumplestiltskin' created=datetime.date(2000, 12, 25) modified=datetime.date(2000, 12, 31) confirmed=datetime.date(2001, 1, 1) closed=datetime.date(2001, 9, 11) number=3
```

Pydantic 2 documentation on [before and after validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/usage/validators/#before-after-wrap-and-plain-validators) and [field validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/usage/validators/#field-validators) is all on the [same page](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/usage/validators).

Comment: This breaks if I have one non-date field in the model. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: File "pydantic/main.py", line 241, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic/class_validators.py", line 189, in pydantic.class_validators.ValidatorGroup.check_for_unused
pydantic.errors.ConfigError: Validators defined with incorrect fields: validate_date (use check_fields=False if you're inheriting from the model and intended this)

Comment: That's funny  @Gibbs, I was using this with a ton of other fields. I hope you didn't put the non-date fields in the `_validate_dates` call? I'm just checking on this but I've moved to Pydantic 2 now so some other things need to change. I'll update my answer if I can.

Comment: To answer you quickly, @Gibbs, this should work with other fields of different types, in Pydantic 2.3 using `field_validator` instead of `validator` and change `pre=True` to `mode='before'` and dropping the `allow_reuse` parameter. The names of the fields that need to be validated need to be listed, so don't put field names in that don't need that particular validator. Again, this is lightly documented or not explicitly documented, which is a bit frustrating, but not that hard to work out by trial and error. I will update the answer to clarify.

Comment: +1 from my end. Thanks for your efforts. And it's due to incorrect spelling of a field name. This works. I am forced to use pydantic < 2 due to non availability of MetaModelClass in pydatnic2+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699451/make-every-field-as-optional-with-pydantic. I see you commented there in the decorator approach.

Comment: Now I am thinking that I should change to pydantic 2 and should update AllOptional implementation.

Comment: I don't know your environment @Gibbs but Pydantic 2 should make everything better and easier, in theory, if your environment can support it. One slight issue with Pydantic 2 is that a lot of the SO solutions are Pydantic 1, but could be migratable I guess. If you're looking at making all fields optional there are some helpful answers around and there is [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167317/make-pydantic-basemodel-fields-optional-including-sub-models-for-patch) around that requirement too.