# Make Pydantic BaseModel fields optional including sub-models for PATCH

Tags: python, fastapi, crud, pydantic

As already asked in ***similar*** questions, I want to support `PATCH` operations for a FastApi application where the caller can specify as many or as few fields as they like, of a Pydantic `BaseModel` ***with sub-models***, so that efficient `PATCH` operations can be performed, without the caller having to supply an entire valid model just in order to update two or three of the fields.

I've discovered there are ***2 steps*** in Pydantic `PATCH` from the [tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-updates/#partial-updates-with-patch) that ***don't support sub-models***. However, Pydantic is far too good for me to criticise it for something that it seems can be built using the tools that Pydantic provides. This question is to request implementation of those 2 things ***while also supporting sub-models***:

1. generate a new DRY `BaseModel` with all fields optional
2. implement deep copy with update of `BaseModel`

These problems are already recognised by Pydantic.

- There is [discussion](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/3089) of a class based solution to the optional model
- And there [two](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4177) [issues](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/3785) open on the deep copy with update

A ***similar*** [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699451) has been asked one or two times here on SO and there are some great answers with different approaches to generating an all-fields optional version of the nested `BaseModel`. After considering them all [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72365032) by [Ziur Olpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10416012/ziur-olpa) seemed to me to be the best, providing a function that takes the existing model with optional and mandatory fields, and returning a new model with *all fields optional*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72365032

The beauty of this approach is that you can hide the (actually quite compact) little function in a library and just use it as a dependency so that it appears in-line in the path operation function and there's no other code or boilerplate.

But the implementation provided in the previous answer did not take the step of dealing with sub-objects in the `BaseModel` being patched.

**This question therefore requests an improved implementation of the all-fields-optional function that also deals with sub-objects, as well as a deep copy with update.**

I have a simple example as a demonstration of this use-case, which although aiming to be simple for demonstration purposes, also includes a number of fields to more closely reflect the real world examples we see. Hopefully this example provides a test scenario for implementations, saving work:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime, date

from collections import defaultdict
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, status, Depends
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

app = FastAPI(title="PATCH demo")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class Collection:
    collection = defaultdict(dict)

    def __init__(self, this, that):
        logging.debug("-".join((this, that)))
        self.this = this
        self.that = that

    def get_document(self):
        document = self.collection[self.this].get(self.that)
        if not document:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                detail="Not Found",
            )
        logging.debug(document)
        return document

    def save_document(self, document):
        logging.debug(document)
        self.collection[self.this][self.that] = document
        return document


class SubOne(BaseModel):
    original: date
    verified: str = ""
    source: str = ""
    incurred: str = ""
    reason: str = ""
    attachments: list[str] = []


class SubTwo(BaseModel):
    this: str
    that: str
    amount: float
    plan_code: str = ""
    plan_name: str = ""
    plan_type: str = ""
    meta_a: str = ""
    meta_b: str = ""
    meta_c: str = ""


class Document(BaseModel):
    this: str
    that: str
    created: datetime
    updated: datetime

    sub_one: SubOne
    sub_two: SubTwo

    the_code: str = ""
    the_status: str = ""
    the_type: str = ""
    phase: str = ""
    process: str = ""
    option: str = ""


@app.get("/endpoint/{this}/{that}", response_model=Document)
async def get_submission(this: str, that: str) -> Document:

    collection = Collection(this=this, that=that)
    return collection.get_document()


@app.put("/endpoint/{this}/{that}", response_model=Document)
async def put_submission(this: str, that: str, document: Document) -> Document:

    collection = Collection(this=this, that=that)
    return collection.save_document(jsonable_encoder(document))


@app.patch("/endpoint/{this}/{that}", response_model=Document)
async def patch_submission(
    document: Document,
    # document: optional(Document),  # <<< IMPLEMENT optional <<<
    this: str,
    that: str,
) -> Document:

    collection = Collection(this=this, that=that)
    existing = collection.get_document()
    existing = Document(**existing)
    update = document.dict(exclude_unset=True)
    updated = existing.copy(update=update, deep=True)  # <<< FIX THIS <<<
    updated = jsonable_encoder(updated)
    collection.save_document(updated)
    return updated
```

This example is a working FastAPI application, following the tutorial, and can be run with `uvicorn example:app --reload`. Except it doesn't work, because there's no all-optional fields model, and Pydantic's deep copy with update actually ***overwrites*** sub-models rather than ***updating*** them.

In order to test it the following Bash script can be used to run `curl` requests. Again I'm supplying this just to hopefully make it easier to get started with this question.
Just comment out the other commands each time you run it so that the command you want is used.
To demonstrate this initial state of the example app working you would run `GET` (expect 404), `PUT` (document stored), `GET` (expect 200 and same document returned), `PATCH` (expect 200), `GET` (expect 200 and updated document returned).

```
host='http://127.0.0.1:8000'
path="/endpoint/A123/B456"

method='PUT'
data='
{
"this":"A123",
"that":"B456",
"created":"2022-12-01T01:02:03.456",
"updated":"2023-01-01T01:02:03.456",
"sub_one":{"original":"2022-12-12","verified":"Y"},
"sub_two":{"this":"A123","that":"B456","amount":0.88,"plan_code":"HELLO"},
"the_code":"BYE"}
'

# method='PATCH'
# data='{"this":"A123","that":"B456","created":"2022-12-01T01:02:03.456","updated":"2023-01-02T03:04:05.678","sub_one":{"original":"2022-12-12","verified":"N"},"sub_two":{"this":"A123","that":"B456","amount":123.456}}' 

method='GET'
data=''

if [[ -n data ]]; then data=" --data '$data'"; fi
curl="curl -K curlrc -X $method '$host$path' $data"
echo $curl >&2
eval $curl
```

This `curlrc` will need to be co-located to ensure the content type headers are correct:

```
--cookie "_cookies"
--cookie-jar "_cookies"
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
--header "Accept: application/json"
--header "Accept-Encoding: compress, gzip"
--header "Cache-Control: no-cache"
```

So what I'm looking for is the implementation of `optional` that is commented out in the code, and a fix for `existing.copy` with the `update` parameter, that will enable this example to be used with `PATCH` calls that omit otherwise mandatory fields.
The implementation does not have to conform precisely to the commented out line, I just provided that based on [Ziur Olpa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10416012/ziur-olpa) previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72365032).

Comment: Consider making this a feature request on the pydantic project: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic

I agree, this problem is oft repeated, there should be some library code to help solve this for you.

Comment: Also, this Q contains a lot of information, hard to understand the essence of what you're asking with that info overload. Is it possible to simplify the Q? Are you looking simply for a recursive "make fields optional" function?

Comment: Thanks @YaakovBressler I appreciate the feedback. Actually I've been working with Zuir_Olpa from the original question and I formulated the question as I was working through it starting with his answer. It is too wordy for sure, and I actually have an implementation already based on Ziur_Olpa 's answer. It's simple enough to almost fit in a comment, but I've discovered along the way that there are further problems with other Pydantic components in order to implement the sub-model PATCH that I'm after. I will try to improve the question.

Comment: Question improved @YaakovBressler: removed additional confusing question from the end, clarified Pydantic problems to solve. Of course the code makes it longer but I hope the code clarifies the use-case and provides a way to get started on the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I first posed this question I thought that the only problem was how to turn all fields `Optional` in a nested `BaseModel`, but actually that was not difficult to fix.

The real problem with partial updates when implementing a `PATCH` call is that the Pydantic `BaseModel.copy` method doesn't attempt to support nested models when applying it's `update` parameter. That's quite an involved task for the generic case, considering you may have fields that are `dict`s, `list`s, or `set`s of another `BaseModel`, just for instance. Instead it just unpacks the `dict` using `**`: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/main.py#L353

I haven't got a proper implementation of that for Pydantic, but since I've got a working example `PATCH` by cheating, I'm going to post this as an answer and see if anyone can fault it or provide better, possibly even with an implementation of `BaseModel.copy` that supports updates for nested models.

Rather than post the implementations separately I am going to update the example given in the question so that it has a working `PATCH` and being a full demonstration of `PATCH` hopefully this will help others more.

The two additions are `partial` and `merge`. `partial` is what's referred to as `optional` in the question code.

***`partial`***:
This is a function that takes any `BaseModel` and returns a new `BaseModel` with all fields `Optional`, including sub-object fields. That's enough for Pydantic to allow through any sub-set of fields without throwing an error for "missing fields". It's recursive - not really popular - but given these are nested data models the depth is not expected to exceed single digits.

***`merge`***:
The `BaseModel` update on copy method operates on an instance of `BaseModel` - but supporting all the possible type variations when descending through a nested model is the hard part - and the database data, and the incoming update, are easily available as plain Python `dict`s; so this is the cheat: `merge` is an implementation of a nested `dict` update instead, and since the `dict` data has already been validated at one point or other, it should be fine.

Here's the full example solution:

```
import logging
from typing import Optional, Type
from datetime import datetime, date
from functools import lru_cache

from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

from collections import defaultdict
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, status, Depends, Body
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

app = FastAPI(title="Nested model PATCH demo")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class Collection:
    collection = defaultdict(dict)

    def __init__(self, this, that):
        logging.debug("-".join((this, that)))
        self.this = this
        self.that = that

    def get_document(self):
        document = self.collection[self.this].get(self.that)
        if not document:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                detail="Not Found",
            )
        logging.debug(document)
        return document

    def save_document(self, document):
        logging.debug(document)
        self.collection[self.this][self.that] = document
        return document


class SubOne(BaseModel):
    original: date
    verified: str = ""
    source: str = ""
    incurred: str = ""
    reason: str = ""
    attachments: list[str] = []


class SubTwo(BaseModel):
    this: str
    that: str
    amount: float
    plan_code: str = ""
    plan_name: str = ""
    plan_type: str = ""
    meta_a: str = ""
    meta_b: str = ""
    meta_c: str = ""

class SubThree(BaseModel):
    one: str = ""
    two: str = ""


class Document(BaseModel):
    this: str
    that: str
    created: datetime
    updated: datetime

    sub_one: SubOne
    sub_two: SubTwo
    # sub_three: dict[str, SubThree] = {}  # Hah hah not really

    the_code: str = ""
    the_status: str = ""
    the_type: str = ""
    phase: str = ""
    process: str = ""
    option: str = ""


@lru_cache
def partial(baseclass: Type[BaseModel]) -> Type[BaseModel]:
    """Make all fields in supplied Pydantic BaseModel Optional, for use in PATCH calls.

    Iterate over fields of baseclass, descend into sub-classes, convert fields to Optional and return new model.
    Cache newly created model with lru_cache to ensure it's only created once.
    Use with Body to generate the partial model on the fly, in the PATCH path operation function.

    - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167317/make-pydantic-basemodel-fields-optional-including-sub-models-for-patch
    - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699451/make-every-fields-as-optional-with-pydantic
    - https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/3089
    - https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-updates/#partial-updates-with-patch
    """
    fields = {}
    for name, field in baseclass.__fields__.items():
        type_ = field.type_
        if type_.__base__ is BaseModel:
            fields[name] = (Optional[partial(type_)], {})
        else:
            fields[name] = (Optional[type_], None) if field.required else (type_, field.default)
    # https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation
    validators = {"__validators__": baseclass.__validators__}
    return create_model(baseclass.__name__ + "Partial", **fields, __validators__=validators)


def merge(original, update):
    """Update original nested dict with values from update retaining original values that are missing in update.

    - https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/3785
    - https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4177
    - https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modelcopy
    - https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/main.py#L353
    """
    for key in update:
        if key in original:
            if isinstance(original[key], dict) and isinstance(update[key], dict):
                merge(original[key], update[key])
            elif isinstance(original[key], list) and isinstance(update[key], list):
                original[key].extend(update[key])
            else:
                original[key] = update[key]
        else:
            original[key] = update[key]
    return original


@app.get("/endpoint/{this}/{that}", response_model=Document)
async def get_submission(this: str, that: str) -> Document:

    collection = Collection(this=this, that=that)
    return collection.get_document()


@app.put("/endpoint/{this}/{that}", response_model=Document)
async def put_submission(this: str, that: str, document: Document) -> Document:

    collection = Collection(this=this, that=that)
    return collection.save_document(jsonable_encoder(document))


@app.patch("/endpoint/{this}/{that}", response_model=Document)
async def patch_submission(
    this: str,
    that: str,
    document: partial(Document),  # <<< IMPLEMENTED partial TO MAKE ALL FIELDS Optional <<<
) -> Document:

    collection = Collection(this=this, that=that)
    existing_document = collection.get_document()
    incoming_document = document.dict(exclude_unset=True)
    # VVV IMPLEMENTED merge INSTEAD OF USING BROKEN PYDANTIC copy WITH update VVV
    updated_document = jsonable_encoder(merge(existing_document, incoming_document))
    collection.save_document(updated_document)
    return updated_document
```

Comment: it is not pickle-able. How could we make it pickle-able?

Comment: I don't normally use `pickle` @Gibbs but AFAI do K there's nothing special about the data transfer itself, it's just relying on the standard FastAPI JSON serialisation. But `pickle` can handle a lot more variety than JSON. I can't image what your problem is. Perhaps I'm not clear what you mean when you say "it", but it sounds like you may need to ask a separate question.